# Finding the dimensions of the cylinder that can cover $n$ given smaller cylinders (based on empty space, not least materials)

Tags: mathematical-optimization, geometry, sorting, scripting

Let $r_k$ and $h_k$ be, respectively, the radius and the height of the $k^\text{th}$ cylinder. We have $n$ cylinders.

Let $R$ and $H$ be, respectively, the radius and the height of the big that can cover the $n$ cylinders.

---

I need to list (from best to worst) all possible dimensions $(R \text{ and } H)$ so that the empty space inside the big cylinder is less.

---

The example may help to get my problem:

Say we have, $r_1=2, h_1=3, r_2=2.5, h=3.8, r_3 = 2, h_3=3.5$

Then we will have the following scenarios:

[image]

That when all of the are next to each other,

[image]

That when we have two layers with the widest being at the top

[image]

That when we have two layers with widest being adjacent to another one, for here we need a bigger radius to fit.

[image]

That when all on each other, here we will have a less radius to fit, but more height,

---

Then we may also have different scenarios

---

I do not need to see the drawings by mathematica, that was only for illustration, but I need $R$ and $H$ (from best to worst). That is according to the minimum empty space (best).

- Note: all cylinders being vertically positioned.

---

Your help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here my solutions looking for an enclosing cylinder with minimal volume:

definitions

```
r[1] = 2; h[1] = 5; r[2] = 2.5; h[2] = 3.8; r[3] = 2; h[3] = 3.5;
p = Table[{x[k], y[k], z[k]}, {k, 1, 3}]
cylR = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, H}}, R] ;
cyl = Table[Cylinder[{{x[k], y[k], z[k]}, {x[k], y[k], z[k] + h[k]}}, 
r[k]], {k, 1, 3}];
```

(* cylinder stack*)

```
zwang = Join[{ (p[[1]] - p[[2]]) . (p[[1]] - p[[2]]) >= (r[1] + 
        r[2])^2,
    (p[[1]] - p[[3]]) . (p[[1]] - p[[3]]) >= (r[1] + 
        r[3])^2, (p[[2]] - p[[3]]) . (p[[2]] - p[[3]]) >= (r[2] + 
        r[3])^2,
    R >= Max[ r[1], r[2], r[3]], H >= Max[h[1], h[2], h[3]] },
   Table[{Sqrt[ x[k] ^2 + y[k] ^2] <= R - r[k], 
      0 <= z[k] <= z[k] + h[k] <= H}, {k, 1, 3}] // Flatten];
mini = NMinimize[{Pi R^2 H, zwang}, {R, H, x[1], y[1], z[1], x[2], 
     y[2], z[2], x[3], y[3], z[3]} , Method -> Automatic ]; // Quiet
mini (*{235.619, {R -> 2.5, H -> 12.,...}*)

Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], cylR, cyl} /. mini[[2]]]
```

[image]

(*cylinders in the same plane*)

```
zwang = Join[{ (p[[1]] - p[[2]]) . (p[[1]] - p[[2]]) >= (r[1] + 
        r[2])^2,
    (p[[1]] - p[[3]]) . (p[[1]] - p[[3]]) >= (r[1] + 
        r[3])^2, (p[[2]] - p[[3]]) . (p[[2]] - p[[3]]) >= (r[2] + 
        r[3])^2,
    R >= Max[ r[1], r[2], r[3]], H == Max[h[1], h[2], h[3]]},
   Table[{Sqrt[ x[k] ^2 + y[k] ^2] <= R - r[k], 
      0 <= z[k] <= z[k] + h[k] <= H}, {k, 1, 3}] // Flatten];
mini = NMinimize[{Pi R^2 H, zwang}, {R, H, x[1], y[1], z[1], x[2], 
     y[2], z[2], x[3], y[3], z[3]} , Method -> Automatic ]; // Quiet
mini (*{337.591, {R -> 4.63592, H -> 5.,...}*)

Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], cylR, cyl} /. mini[[2]]]
```

[image]

The three other cases follow if you change the constraint `H == Max[h[1], h[2], h[3]]}` in the last block to `H == h[1]+ h[2]` ,`H == h[1]+ h[3]` ,`H == h[2]+ h[3]`

Hope it helps!

Comment: First, thanks for answering. Actually I am not looking for minimizing the volume of the biggest cylinder, but looking for minimizing the empty volume. So my input should have the form: ${(r_1,h_1),(r_2,h_2),(r_3,h_3),(r_4,h_4), ... , (r_n,h_n)}$ and the output should be of the form: ${(R_1,H_1), ... , (R_m,H_m)}$, arranged in order, regarding the empty space volume (not the big cylinder volume). So for some cases, $m$ may be large. That is, $n$ and $m$ are not necessarily equal.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari My answer minimizes the volume of the enclosing cylinder which equals  empty volume+volumes of the inner cylinders!!

Comment: I tried the coding, but did not work for me. Also it seems like the code cannot work for any arbitrary $n$, say for example we have $27$ inner cylinders, then? Further, the code should give the outputs for all scenarios (from best to worst), can you check it and modify it, please?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari My answer is intended to give you an examplary  idea how to solve the problm. Generalization is up to you!

Comment: Still for the exemplary idea, I did not get the output in the required form: R1=..., H1= ..., R2=..., H2=...., and so on (in order from best case to worst case). Can you help, please?

Comment: Try after evaluation of mini `{R,H,Pi R^2 H}/.mini[[2]]`

Comment: Yes, that is good, with that it gives me the minimum, but did not show all scenarios. My problem is about (I give) the dimensions of $n$ cylinders, then (it gives) $R$'s and $H$'s from best to worst.